# Getting Task :react-native-custom-keyboard-kit:verifyReleaseResources FAILED when building app

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create a simple app with **Custom Keyboard**. So I used **react-native-custom-keyboard-kit** npm package. It has no error when the app running on debugging mode. But when I tried to build app, it occured error as below:

> Task :react-native-custom-keyboard-kit:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-custom-keyboard-kit:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> /home/bipulroy/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a4aa75ad6ccbe3ab81ae94031ca63766/appcompat-1.0.2/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

Comment: are u solve it?

Comment: No brother. I didn't get any response from its owner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the library natively?

Try this:

```
react-native link react-native-custom-keyboard-kit
```